# I need Ajax .on to fire on the second .on and not the first

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having difficulty with [chained selects](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained) firing my ajax call intended to happen .on change.  The problem is, when Chained Select populated the second select (the one I'm intending to use to call ajax) it fires the ajax call prematurely.

Is it possible to skip the first .on and fire from the second .change subsequently?

Chained Selects Function:

```
  $(function() {    
            $("#products").remoteChained({  
                parents: "#instrument",
                url: "/ajax/instrument",
                loading: "loading",

            });       
  });
```

My Ajax Function:

```
$('#products').on('change', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value');
    console.log('href ' + href);
    location.hash = href;
    $('#sort').hide();
    $('#sort').css({ display: 'block' }).animate({ height: '100%'
    }, function() {

        $('#sort').fadeIn('slow').html('<div class="clearfix loading"> LOADING </div>');
        $('#loader').css({ border: 'none', position: 'relative', top: '24px', left: '48px', boxShadow: 'none'
        }); 
     // http://loadinfo.net/
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ajax/ajax_sort/" + href,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#sort").html(data);
          $('.c3 .card').equalHeights();
                $('.product-count').fadeOut('slow');
                $('#ajax-hidden').hide().fadeOut('slow');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can't you do a conditional ajax call as you explicit want to have the user change the value? `if(href !== 'your default') $ajax...`

Comment: download from [github](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_chained/blob/master/jquery.chained.remote.js) and remove the `.trigger('change')` events.

Comment: If there was a way to vote this up, I would.  That worked like a charm.  I didn't have to remove the .trigger, I just changed them to .on and it works like a charm.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Oh... there is a way.  What a noob.  Thanks man, I've been bean beating myself for hours over this.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use a boolean variable to check

```
var shouldRun = false;
$('#products').on('change', function(event) {
if(!shouldRun)
{
    shouldRun = true;
    return;
}
//Your code
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks!  The only problem is, when the user goes back to the first select, and changes another option, the same thing happens.  Maybe I need to reference .off on the first select?

Comment: _The only problem is_, this is exactly what I thought when I seen this answer.